# Как получить подтверждение выполнения sql запроса если не было затронуто строк

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

возникла необходимость удалять строки в бд по условию, проблема в том что когда sql запрос выполняется успешно, но количество затрагиваемых строк равно нулю я не могу определить выполнился запрос или нет. Для выполнения sql использую следующий код:

```
public boolean checkRequest(String sql) throws IOException, PropertyVetoException, SQLException {
    Connection connection = DataSource.getInstance().getConnection();
    Statement stmt = null;
    stmt = connection.createStatement();
    int rs = stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
    if (rs != 0) {
        stmt.close();
        session.closeConnection(connection);
        return true;
    }
    stmt.close();
    session.closeConnection(connection);
    return false;
 }
```

sql выглядит следующим образом:

```
String sql = "DELETE FROM data_history WHERE \"create\" < now()-make_interval(hours := 48 )";
```

В случае если происходит удаление нескольких PosgreSQL выдает:

> DELETE 5
>   Query returned successfully in 75 msec.

В случае если запрос выполняет, но удаление строк не происходит PosgreSQL выдает:

> DELETE 0
>   Query returned successfully in 75 msec.

Как мне получить successfully после выполнения запроса?

Comment: У вас при исключении вызывается SQLException, следовательно если он не вызвался- удаление прошло успешно.

Comment: Вы же проверяете if (rs != 0)... Если равно 0, то ваш метод вернет false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обрабатывайте исключение:

```
    public class Test {
        public boolean checkRequest(String sql) throws Exception {
            try (Connection connection = DataSource.getInstance().getConnection();) {
                try (Statement stmt = connection.createStatement()) {
                    stmt.execute(sql);
                    return true;
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Красиво и лаконично, спасибо!)